# Phonetic pronunciation help for "秋子/Autumn Child" - Chinese trad

Tags: pronunciation, names

Trying to figure out the laymans phonetic spelling for 秋子 (Qiūzi: Autumn Child.)

The closest I've been able to come is Chee-Oh-tsö (because the umlaut 'o' makes an oo sound).

But this still seems wrong. Any help for a newbie?

Comment: there's audio here: http://hanyu.baidu.com/zici/s?wd=%E7%A7%8B%E5%AD%90&query=%E7%A7%8B%E5%AD%90&srcid=28232&from=kg0&from=kg0#

Comment: More audio here, by clicking on the speaker icon at the bottom left side of the text field: https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E7%A7%8B%E5%AD%90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't hear a "oo" sound in 子。 It's more like a "z" without much of a vowel sound after it. To spell it out in laymans phonetic, I suggest: chee-Oh-Tzz  (or just one z) (Edit: or chee-Oh-Tzh, so as not to imply a buzzing sound?)

Comment: Thanks. You sure you don't hear the oo? (the google translate you showed me is slowed down and I still can't unhear it. that said, I original heard it and thought it similar to 'tze' but it's hard to elongate that. I struggle with the fact that a double z has a buzzing to it that I don't hear in any of the audio translations. How do you avoid that?

Comment: Yes, the implied buzzing is bothering me too. Perhaps chee-Oh-Tzh to replace the buzzing with a breath? As for the oo, I don't hear it. I am curious to hear the opinion of anyone else who wants to chime in.

Comment: I think that is probably as close as I'll come without more practice. Thank you Max.